# Differentiation and limit problem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Define $f: R \to R$ as $f(x)=a_1sinx+a_2sin2x+ \cdots +a_nsinnx$

and suppose for all $x \in R$ $|f(x)| \le |sinx|$.

Prove that $|a_1+2a_2+ \cdots +na_n| \le 1$.

I've almost solved this problem but there is one thing in the last step that I'm unsure about.

Solution:

$|a_1+2a_2+ \cdots +na_n|=|f'(0)|=|lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}|=lim_{x\to0}|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}|=lim_{x\to0}(|\frac{f(x)}{sinx}||\frac{sinx}{x}|)$

And in the last step I'm guessing that since $|\frac{f(x)}{sinx}| \le 1$ the last part of the above equation is bounded above by $lim_{x\to0}|\frac{sinx}{x}|$, which is $1$.

However, I'm not sure if this is correct, since isn't it possible that even if the function is bounded above at all points, the limit at a specific point is undefined or tends to infinity? How can I manipulate the last part to prove this?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems correct. Since $ f(x) $ is a addition of continuous functions
( $ Sin $ ). So it has limit everywhere and also $ - |Sin x| \leq f(x) \leq |Sin x| $ , so $ f(x) $ can't go to infinity.

Comment: But in this case since the limit of sinx as x goes to 0 is 0, we cant use the quotient rule for limits and so isnt there the possibility that the limit |f(x)/sinx| goes to infinity? How can I guarantee that the limit is bounded?

Comment: Can we use L'hospital rule for $ |f(x)/sin x| $ to find limit for it.

Comment: I guess we could solve it that way but this problem is in the textbook before the introduction of L'hopital so I was wondering if there was another way of figuring it out